# Problem making a button bigger using animation in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a button of a certain size. When I use a storyboard etc. to enlarge it, it gets clipped to the original button size even though it is enlarging.

Comment: I think we'll need a little more detail than that. How are you enlarging it? Show us some code.

Comment: Are you using ViewBox or fixed size panel wrapped around the button? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are animating a `ScaleTransform` used as the `RenderTransform`: This will not consider layout, move it to the `LayoutTransform` and animate it there.